# Is it possible to show taxonomy terms in a views filter sorted alphabetically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have some content that is classified using a two-level taxonomy:
Accommodation -> B&B
Accommodation -> Hotels
Accommodation -> Self Catering
Things to Do -> Arts & Crafts
Things to Do -> Family attractions
Eating out -> Cafes
Eating out -> Restaurants

In some situations, I need to display all these categories together in views as a taxonomy filter.

When I do that, they are displayed grouped by the parent term, so they look weirdly random.  Is it possible to break them out from their parent term and show them in the filter sorted alphabetically, or alternatively, show the parent term as well as the child term, so that it's clear why the terms are sorted like that?

I am on Drupal 7, Views 3.11.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade taxonomy and views to the latest version and select the following options.

[image]

And when the filters terms are being listed, they will be listed in alphabetic order.

[image]

You can confirm that there is hierarchy in terms and they are not alphabtic in order.

[image]

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, but I can't find it - I'm on Drupal 7.38, Views 3.11, and when I edit the filter, the only options I can see are : Dropdown, Autocomplete and Show hierarchy in Dropdown.   Where would I find these extra settings?